# Restrict user to update model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using Django auth for my model `Dish`. Each user manages many dishes (1-n relationship)

```py
# models.py
class Dish(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

# views.py
class ProfileFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login'
    template_name = 'dish.html'
    model = Dish
    success_url = '/dish/updated'
```

I want to restrict my UpdateView to only dish's owner (For example: user 1 owns dish 1 and 2; user 2 owns dish 3 and 4. user 1 can edit dish 1, but cannot edit dish 3 or 4). Assuming that user manages other models (for example: menu, ratings, etc), and they all need to be restricted to their owners.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: if your user_id  correctly associated to your user, then setting LoginRequiredMixin should do fine. you can use get_object_or_404(Model, pk=pk, user_id=request.user.id) too

Comment: @RezaGH Thank you very much. Although it is not the answer for this case, it helps me for other functions.

Comment: sorry i don't know alot about CBV (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`UserPassesTestMixin`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) class as

```
class ProfileFormView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    UserPassesTestMixin,
    UpdateView
):
    login_url = '/accounts/login'
    template_name = 'dish.html'
    model = Dish
    success_url = '/dish/updated'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user_id
```

Alternatively, you can override the **`get_queryset(...)`** method as

```
class ProfileFormView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    UpdateView
):
    login_url = '/accounts/login'
    template_name = 'dish.html'
    model = Dish
    success_url = '/dish/updated'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user_id=self.request.user)
```

Also, in Django, we don't reference the FK (or M2M) objects with a ***`_id`*** suffix. So, better change the field **`user_id`** to **`user`**

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and suggestion.